# Inheritance, protocols and static fields

Tags: ios, swift, macos

How can I get rid of repetition here for the fields `id` and `commonStaticField`?

```
struct S1 {
  let id: String       //note - it's let
  static let commonStaticField = "s1" //note - it's static
  let someField1: String
  let someField2: String
}

struct S2 {
  let id: String
  static let commonStaticField = "s2"
  let someField3: String
  let someField4: String
}
```

I've tried to use this with different variations:

```
protocol P1 {
  let id: String
  static let commonStaticField: String //static not allowed
}
```

but it didn't pan out. I'd like to be able to do this:

```
struct S1: P1 {
  static let commonStaticField = "s1" //note - it's static and defined
  let someField1: String
  let someField2: String
}

let s1 = S1(id: "some id", someField1: "some field3", someField2: "some field2")
```

Comment: You could make a class and a subclass because structs don't support inheritance or you could make one struct and just have one property that designates if it is S1 or S2

Comment: @Bluehound, in the 1st case, how can I make the 2 fields abstract in the base class?

Comment: @Bluehound, if the 2nd case, what if I have 50 different structures?